# Grails Atmosphere Implementation

Tags: grails, atmosphere

I am trying to implement auto update feature in my application using atmosphere plugin. I am also planning to use the same plugin to create a chat application. I have searched all over for proper documentation but I could not find any. Can you please direct me to a proper tutorial explaining the use of this plugin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the Atmosphere github project](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere), with links to the documentation, tutorials, FAQ, and javadocs.

[Here's the project for the Grails plugin](https://bitbucket.org/bgoetzmann/grails-atmosphere-plugin/wiki/Home), with what looks to be an extensive "Getting Started" right there in the readme.